# Bluestacks click simulator

Tags: java, game, simulation

I would like to simulate clicks inside a game which is running inside [Bluestacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/). Im thinking of taking a screenshot of my screen, crop on x1, y1 to x2, y2 vertices to only have the Bluestacks screen inside the image. I would then look for an image inside an image (monster image inside Bluestacks image), get the coordinates of the monster image, and click it. Is this the best way to do it? If so, what software can I use to take a screenshot of another application (image of contents inside frame)? What software can I use to find images inside a larger image? Even better, is there a software that I can use to communicate directly with Bluestacks? Thank you.